# Как добавить свойство transform(translate) и добавить событие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, css

Есть галерея хочу сделать плавный переход между картинками при нажатии на кнопку (стрелка влево,стрелка вправо) Сейчас в коде при наведении на главную картинку , картинка сдвигается вправо , но как повесить на стрелку событие чтобы при нажатии на них она плавно переходила и заменяла другие картинки?

```
 var thumbnails = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img'));
function clickOnThumbnail(event) {
    document.querySelector('.image-main').src = this.dataset.fullUrl;
}
for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnThumbnail);
};

;(function arrows(){
    var leftArrow = document.getElementById('arrowleft'),
        rightArrow = document.getElementById('arrowright'),
        initImgNumber = 1;
    maxImgNum = 14;

    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', moveBackvard);
    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', moveForvard);

    function moveBackvard(){
        var image = document.getElementById('image-main');
        initImgNumber--;
        if (initImgNumber == 0){initImgNumber = maxImgNum};
        image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gallery/big/' + initImgNumber + '.jpg');
    };

    function moveForvard(){
        var image = document.getElementById('image-main');
        initImgNumber++;
        if (initImgNumber > maxImgNum){initImgNumber = 1};
        image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gallery/big/' + initImgNumber + '.jpg');
    };
})();
        <div class="gallery__wrapper">
        <div class="image-main__wrapper">
            <img class="image-main" src="images/fullsize/1.jpg" id="image-main">
                <div class="arrowleft"><img src="images/left.jpg" id="arrowleft"/></div>
                <div class="arrowright"><img src="images/right.jpg" id="arrowright"/></div>
            <div class="image-thumbnails__wrapper">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li><img id="thumb-1" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/1.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-2" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/2.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-3" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/3.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-4" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/4.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-5" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/5.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-6" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/6.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-7" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/7.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-8" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/8.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-9" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/9.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-10" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/10.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-11" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/11.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/11.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-12" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/12.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-13" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/13.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/13.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-14" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/14.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/14.jpg"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.arrowleft {
    position:relative;
    top:205px;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}
.arrowright {
    position:relative;
    left:711px;
    top:205px;
    width:40%;
    float:right;
}
.arrowleft img{
    width:100%;
}
.arrowright img{
    width:100%;
}

.arrowleft img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:95%;
}
.arrowleft img:active{
    width:85%;
}
.arrowright img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:95%;
}
.arrowright img:active{
    width:85%;
}
.gallery__wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
}
.image-main__wrapper{

}
.image-main{
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0;

}
#image-main{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#image-main:hover{
    -webkit-transform: translate(5px,0);
}
.image-thumbnails__wrapper{
   width:785px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:450px;

}
.thumbnails{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.thumbnails img{
    border: 2px solid dimgray;
    margin: 0px 1px 17px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как бы дел этих дел есть [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

> 2. Как добавить свойство transform(translate) --

Элемент.style = "transform: translate();"

Или если подклчен JQuery то $('Элемент').css ("transform", "translate()");

> добавить событие на кнопку

[Здесь](http://vvz.nw.ru/Lessons/JavaScript/events.htm) список всех событий. Они записываются в атрибуты.